# CSS formatting multi-page print

Tags: css, printing

I've got the following code and I'm trying to use CSS2 or CSS3 to make it so the content appears below the header on each page when in print preview.

Is this possible?
It seems to work correctly on the first page but then every page after that the header sits on top of my content.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<style>
@media print {

h1 {
  position:fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#content {
  padding-top: 100px;
}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Testing printing CSS</h1>

<div id=content>
<p>Testing</p><p>Testing</p><p>Testing</p><p>Testing</p><p>Testing</p><p>Testing</p><p>Testing</p><p>Testing</p><p>Testing</p><p>Testing</p><p>Testing</p><p>Testing</p><p>Testing</p><p>Testing</p><p>Testing</p><p>Testing</p><p>Testing</p><p>Testing</p><p>Testing</p><p>Testing</p><p>Testing</p><p>Testing</p><p>Testing</p><p>Testing</p><p>Testing</p><p>Testing</p><p>Testing</p><p>Testing</p><p>Testing</p><p>Testing</p><p>Testing</p><p>Testing</p><p>Testing</p><p>Testing</p><p>Testing</p><p>Testing</p>
</div>
</body> </html>
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at page-break-before. I think this is a CSS attribute. I have to say I havent looked into printing before, particularly not multi-page. I dont know how you would ensure there was a header on every page without using page-break-before, particularly if it was one continuous block of text spread over 3 pages. Of course I think you can set the width and height of an element to xcm (x amount of centimetres) so if you know the page size then you may be able to do something with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Margin Boxes in the [CSS3 Paged Media Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/#margin-boxes):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Print Test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      @page {
        @top-center {
          content: "Testing printing CSS";
        }
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Testing</p><p>Testing</p><p>Testing</p><p>Testing</p><p>Testing</p><p>Testing</p><p>Testing</p><p>Testing</p><p>Testing</p><p>Testing</p><p>Testing</p><p>Testing</p><p>Testing</p><p>Testing</p><p>Testing</p><p>Testing</p><p>Testing</p><p>Testing</p><p>Testing</p><p>Testing</p><p>Testing</p><p>Testing</p><p>Testing</p><p>Testing</p><p>Testing</p><p>Testing</p><p>Testing</p><p>Testing</p><p>Testing</p><p>Testing</p><p>Testing</p><p>Testing</p><p>Testing</p><p>Testing</p><p>Testing</p><p>Testing</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Be forewarned: this is relatively [unsupported](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_%28Cascading_Style_Sheets%29#Grammar_and_rules), even in modern browsers.

Comment: Modern Browsers, your not wrong I tested that code under Firefox 3.6.10 and Google Chromium 6.0.472.62 and it didn't work at all.

Comment: This answer suggests using the paged media margin boxes which are not supported in ANY major browsers yet. Please refer to the information provided in  [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_%28Cascading_Style_Sheets%29#Grammar_and_rules) comparison. It is not *relatively* unsupported. It is not supported. Period. Still, even after almost 5 years. Unless you are using a commertial layout engine like [Prince](http://www.princexml.com/).

Comment: Seems to be the case, Prince... everyone speaks of it, but I never made it work in webkit anyway or wkhtml2pdf.